# Target all the following sibling's children

Tags: jquery

When the user is changing a `select` I need to empty every `select` that comes after that one.
So for example, if you change the middle one, only the last `select` is emptied.

```
<div>
    <select></select>
</div>
<div>
    <select></select>
</div>
<div>
    <select></select>
</div>
```

I tried this but couldn't get it to work:

```
$("select").change(function () {
  $(this).parent().nextAll("div select").empty();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function returns a collection of only the following **siblings**. The selector argument can only filter that collection.

So, in order to do what you're trying to do, after you find all the following `divs`, you have to use the [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function to get the `select` elements which are its direct descendents (or [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to reach every descendent not only the direct ones).

```
$("select").change(function () {
  $(this).parent().nextAll("div").children("select").empty();
});
```